# Show css3 animate for 2 times

Tags: jquery, css, animation

i design bootstrap error box using flash CSS3 animate Like This code:

HTML:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger flashit">error error</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flashit {
    -webkit-animation: flash linear 1s infinite;
    animation: flash linear 1s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes flash {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: .1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@keyframes flash {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: .1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

this worked and work flash animated But, i need to show two times flash animate effect.

How do create this?

DEMO [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3L6fcdae/)

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/3L6fcdae/1/?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the property [animation-iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count) that property works this way

> defines the number of times an animation cycle should be played before stopping

In the shorthand you can add the value after the duration-time replacing the `infinite` value:

```
-webkit-animation: flash linear 1s 2 forwards;
animation: flash linear 1s 2 forwards;
```

Check your **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3L6fcdae/1/)**

*Note I use `forwards` for the [fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) of the animation keeping the last keyframe*

Comment: Thank you for highlighting fill-mode. Very useful property.

Comment: /* @keyframes name | duration | easing-function | delay | iteration-count | direction */

Answer (score 0):

Change `flash linear 1s infinite` to `flash linear 1s 2`.

The fourth argument there is the repetition count.  Same thing as [animation-iteration-count](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-iteration-count.asp).